# Error in Android's "Building a Simple User Interface" tutorial

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm attempting to follow along with Android's "Building a Single User Interface" tutorial using Eclipse, but I'm getting two errors that are keeping my code from running.

The first error is in res/menu/main.xml ad says:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/
>    action_settings').

The line of code that is giving me that error is:

```
android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

My second error is in res/values/strings.xml and says:

> error: Found tag String where item is 
>    expected

for the line

```
<String name="menu_settings">Settings</String>
```

The entire "String.xml" file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <String name="menu_settings">Settings</String>
    <String name ="title_activity_main">MainActivity</String>
    <String name ="action_settings">Settings</String>

</resources>
```

Though I'm experienced in using Java/Eclipse, I'm new to Android and XML, so I have absolutely no idea what these errors mean. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `String` to `string` (lowercase 's'). The uppercase S makes it invalid and you get the second error. Since that definition is invalid, you get the first error when you try to reference it in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and fixed in the main.xml by changing

```
android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

to

```
android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```

As the strings.xml read

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

Basically, I am saying to those who stumble upon this: make sure to check your naming in the respective files